# Asp.net update DropDownList selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm stuck into a problem using a DropDownList item into a form.
The main form is feed by an SQLDataSource ... all form widget are bound to a specific record field etc.
I changed one of the form widget (a TextBox) with a DropDownList to allow the user to only select between a number of values... I feed this control trough another SQLDataSource. While the form is in Insert mode there are no problems but when I switch into Edit mode I'm not able to set the DropDownList selected item with the value coming from the main record. Ho can I fix this?
Here's a sample of my .aspx code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="_frmData" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="_sdsTable1" DefaultMode="Insert">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="_txtField0" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("field0")%>'/>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlField1" runat="server" DataSourceID="_sdsTable2" DataTextField="field_text" DataValueField="field_value" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="None" Selected="True" />
     </asp:DropDownList>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="_txtField0" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("field0")%>'/>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlField1" CssClass="input_medium" runat="server" DataSourceID="_sdsTable2" DataTextField="field_text" DataValueField="field_value" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
           <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="None" Selected="True" />
     </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="_sdsTable1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_db %>"
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_db.ProviderName %>"
                    SelectCommand=" SELECT
                                        field0, field1
                                    FROM
                                        table1
                                    WHERE
                                        id=@id;"
                    UpdateCommand=" UPDATE
                                        table1
                                    SET
                                       `field0` = @field0
                                       `field1` = @field1
                                    WHERE
                                        id = @id;""
                    InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"
                    InsertCommand="create_table1_entry">
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="field1" ControlID="_frmData$_ddlField1" Type="String" PropertyName="SelectedItem.Text" />
</InsertParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="field1" ControlID="_frmData$_ddlField1" Type="String" PropertyName="SelectedItem.Text" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="_sdsTable2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_db %>"
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_db.ProviderName %>"
                    SelectCommand=" SELECT
                                        field_value, field_text
                                    FROM
                                        table2;" />
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Please share some code snippet

Comment: Halo @JamieRees. I would like to avoid code-behind as much as possibile. But of course if there's no other way I'll use it...

Comment: If only I could use a `SelectedValue='<%#Bind("field1")%>'` property in DDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I CAN JUST use SelectedValue='<%#Bind("field1")%>' property in DDL to achieve the result, just as I was guessing. The only issue here is the why Intellisense is not suggesting SelectedValue as a propery for DropDownList ... thnx everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This

myDropDown.Items.FindByValue("Your Main Record Value").Selected=true;
```

OR

```
myDropDown.Items.FindByText("Your Main Record Text").Selected=true;
```

Comment: the real problem is not how to select the value in the dropdown list but how to bound the selected item to the field value of the record that's feeding the whole form. I.e. if I change the record I'm looking (moving into the table)  in the form all the textbox feed 'Bound' to the record field are updated... the dropdown list it's not since it's bound just to it's datasource and not to the record it's meant to feed. It's an easy task to put the value coming from the DDL to trough a <ControlParameter> entry in the SQLDataSource but with edit mode this's will not work since DDL it's not bound.

Comment: Anyway.. how do you suggest to put this code ? I mean in which event handler?